# Set child's width to the height of the parent in pure CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can I set the *width* of a `child-div` equal to that of it's `parent-div` *height* in pure CSS?

> [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/evk9a9ma/)

So far, I have been doing in jQuery:

```
$("#child-div").width($("#child-div").parent().height());
```

Is this achievable in Pure CSS? For some reasons, I need this to be in Pure CSS. 
Here's my html:

```
<div id="parent-div">
    <div id="child-div>Hello</div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#parent-div{
    background:#ddd;
    height:80%;
    width:30%; position:absolute;
}

#child-div{
    position:relative;
    background:#333;
    color:#FFF;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform-origin: 0 0 ;
    top:100%;
    height: /* What ???? */;
}
```

Any tricks?

Comment: Why don't you do that in jQuery itself?

Comment: @selu I need this is CSS, Please read the question. It's dynamic. Else, I will have to do jquery evry time the window resizes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on this specific demo, you could use [viewport relative units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths) and it will work as expected.

Use `width: 80vh` in this case - [**updated example**](http://jsfiddle.net/2zp32umj/). You can find browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Since `#parent-div` has a height of `80%` of the viewport, you can use `80vh` to set `#child-div`'s width to the same height. This clearly won't work if `#parent-div` doesn't have a height of `80%` of the viewport, though.

As an alternative, you would have to avoid rotating the child element, and just rotate the parent element and give the child element a height of `100%`.

Comment: Thanks @Josh. That's exactly what I was looking for. I need to rotate the child for some reasons.