# How to make a box fit the height of it's parent?

Tags: css

Is there any way in pure CSS to make a square div fit the height of it's parent?
For example if a parent div has width of 1000px but height of 300px then this child div will automatically become 300px by 300px.

I have found multiple examples of divs automatically adjusting their height and width from the parent width using paddingtop but nothing height based

Answer (score 1):

Just give it `height: 100%` - this refers to the height of the parent element. The width by default is auto, so it will remain in the right proportion.

Answer (score 0):

`inherit` property is used for this purpose. However, the inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value from its parent element. Therefore with pure CSS, you can't do this. For example,

```
span {
    color: blue;
}

.extra span {
    color: inherit;
}
```

You **can't** say the following for the child:

```
.extra span {
   background-color: inherit;
}
```

Because there is no initialized value for `background-color` attribute for the parent div.

Comment: That'll make the height equal to the parent but make no difference to the width which I want to match the height

Comment: Yes, it copies directly the value of the attribute of the parent div, if it exists.

Comment: @user2330270 I found one question which is similar to yours. Please, take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320858/set-childs-width-to-the-height-of-the-parent-in-pure-css

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different approach and make the outer parents height size to the height of its child.

```
.parent {
   width:100%;
   overflow:auto;
}

.child{
   height:20vw;
   width:20vw;
}
```

That way you can size the child as you wish, say in this case a square with height and width of 20vw and the parents height will then expand to match its child.

Comment: Isn't vh/vw based on window height/width and not a parent div?

Comment: Yes you are correct, vh/vw is based on the window. I chose that unit because it would keep the square divs aspect the same on a different screen sizes like a mobile device. You could use px but then the inner child div would be a fixed size and as a result less responsive.

Comment: So essentially this solution is sizing the parent based on the child, as opposed to making the child fit its parents height. The child is a 20vw by  20vw square and the parent becomes a 100% width and 20vw height rectangle. Does this help solve the problem?

Comment: Nope. I found a duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707519/div-square-width-size-based-on-100-height but I want a css answer based on a parent div not screen size

Comment: Does the parent need to be a particular size or height? Does the child square shaped div need to be a particular height?

Comment: Nope parent is unknown. Its basically for a plugin I'm making so the parent is whatever someone else decides in height

Comment: So lets say the plug in will be 400px by 400px. You could use the CSS I gave earlier and set the child to 400px by 400px and the parent div would then become 400px height. So the height of the parent and the child match, is this not what you wanted? Yes the child sets the height rather than the parent but without using a padding hack or JavaScript I cannot think of another pure CSS solution. Any way, I hope you find an answer you need.